Differences between formal and talmudic logic
Are there any differences between the formal and talmudic logic?
Specially in terms of usage of true/false and coherences with https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic, or, further, with more-valued logics, as in
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-manyvalued/#SysManValLog

@RabbiKaii the question is indeed similar, but the answers there do not go into the meat and potatoes of the logic formalism as this OP.

Another difference (for my money, the main difference) between Talmudic and formal logic is that Talmud reasoning is abductive, rather than deductive.  That is, it generally begins with a conclusion, poses the question "How do we know that this conclusion is correct?", and then seeks proof-texts (either in the written text of the Torah or in a baraita or other Rabbinic source) to justify the conclusion.  Deductive reasoning, in contrast, begins with a premise that is taken to be true and tries to reason towards a conclusion.
Imagine a hypothetical person who, instead of reasoning abductively, tries to analyze Jewish law deductively.  Such a person might start with one or more proof-texts and reason his way forward towards a conclusion.  It's quite likely that such deductive reasoning might lead to a conclusion that we "know" is wrong.  It's not necessarily that the premises of the argument are wrong, or that the logical structure contains errors in reasoning; rather, we know post hoc that the argument must be wrong because we already know what the correct conclusion is.
(As a not-so-hypothetical example of this, consider a person who begins with the Biblical text "Whoever kidnaps a man and sells him, or if he is found in his possession, must be put to death" (Shemot 21:16) and argues his way towards the conclusion that, since Joseph's brothers were never put to death for the sin of selling him into slavery, the Rabbis of the current generation are liable to be put to death. This is, of course, precisely what is narrated in the "Eileh Ezkerah" section of the Yom Kippur Musaf.)


The reason why the Talmud generally reasons towards a predefined conclusion is because it's a commentary on the Mishnah (which is the predefined conclusion). When commenting on Torah verses, e.g. as midrash halacha, we do reason with the verses as a starting point and the law as the conclusion; there's nothing invalid about this kind of reasoning. 2. The kidnapping reasoning is just a bad analogy (inductive reasoning), but induction is also part of Talmudic logic (binyan av).


Yes, quite a few. Thankfully, a professor of mathematical logic has given an audio class on this.

It has been years since I listened to it, so I can not make this a high quality answer by summarising it right now but will do when I review it. If anyone knows of a free transcription service, I can review it more easily, otherwise I will probably listen to it again sometime soon now that it's on my mind - anyone else is free to edit my answer if they listen to it and wish to summarise. I would be very grateful
